# Autodesk Forge External ID for Navisworks File

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-navisworks

We are trying to export dimensional properties for elements using Forge Viewer with `getBulkProperties` method. For Revit files, the method works fine, but for Navisworks files, we cannot get any useful properties directly.

As we investigate into the problem, we found that the all the `externalId` for Navisworks file are in the format of slash separated integers (e.g. `1/2/2/1/1`). If we chop off the last integer from `externalId` (in this case, using `1/2/2/1`), and get the properties of the corresponding element, then we can have some useful dimensional properties, and the value matches the information we see on desktop version of Navisworks.

Does the `externalId` for Navisworks encoding implies a tree structure? (I am assuming `1/2/2/1` is the parent of `1/2/2/1/1` in this case). What could explain our issue that by just chopping off the last integer, we can get the information we need? Is this a reliable way to get dimensional properties?

A small experiment to reproduce this in Chrome console:

```
selected = AutodeskViewer.getSelection()[0]

AutodeskViewer.getProperties(selected, console.log)
/* {dbId: Array(1), properties: Array(0), externalId: "12/6/0/0/0/0"} */
/* We don't have any useful properties here */

// Get External ID mapping
map = {}; AutodeskViewer.model.getExternalIdMapping(ext_map => {map = ext_map})

// Chopoff the last integer, and run getProperties again
AutodeskViewer.getProperties(map['12/6/0/0/0'], console.log)
/* {dbId: 78085, properties: Array(151), externalId: "12/6/0/0/0", name: "Floor"} */
/* We get useful dimensional properties */
```

Comment: as far as I know, such id 1/2/2/1/1 happens with the Navisworks file if the source file is IFC. The corresponding property in IFC is GlobalID. Typically, model.getExternalMapping of Forge Viewer should store the map between such id and dbid(in Forge Viewer session). I think you are right it implies the node sequence in the tree structure. It would only change if the node is removed of the tree is organized in the source model file (say IFC）

Comment: We also thought it only applied to Navisworks created from IFC file before, but we found we also have the same `externalId` format for several Navisworks files from Revit as well.

Comment: Hi @Chang, could you share a demo Revit file to forge.help At autodesk.com ? I will test and send to engineer team to diagnose. Thanks.